Avoiding Batching of Concurrent Remoting Calls with LCC.callApex in Salesforce
I am developing a managed package in Salesforce where I have integrated Angular as a static resource. From the Angular application, I make remoting calls to Apex methods using LCC.callApex. However, when I send multiple remoting requests concurrently, Salesforce seems to batch or bundle these requests into a single transaction, potentially due to the "boxcarring" mechanism.
As a result, if one of the remoting calls triggers a CPU-intensive operation, it can cause the entire transaction to exceed the Apex CPU time limit, leading to a governor limit exception. This issue becomes more prominent when dealing with multiple concurrent requests, each with different sets of parameters or different operations.
I have researched this problem, but I couldn't find a way to disable the batching or "boxcarring" behavior specifically for LCC.callApex calls. I would appreciate if you could provide a solution or workaround to ensure that each remoting call executed through LCC.callApex is handled as a separate transaction, regardless of the number of concurrent requests or the operations being performed.
If possible, please provide relevant reference links or articles that you used to understand and address this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to effectively handle multiple concurrent remoting calls without hitting governor limits would be greatly appreciated.
(I can't use async method as I want return response)

Boxcarring certainly used to have a bug where the boxcarred requests shared the same limits, though this bug was fixed a few releases back. Are you saying this issue still exists with VF Remoting?

@PhilW Visualforce remoting hasn't been updated in... forever or so. So, it's no surprise that Visualforce's remoting still has the boxcar effect, and that it has the same limitations that Aura/LWC boxcar effects had historically.

@sfdcfox we've used non-buffering to turn off boxcarring in VF, which was supported from a long time back, but I wasn't aware that it still applied a single set of limits to all boxcarred requests (unlike LWC/Aura).

I have solved the issue ,I used the buffer option provided by LCC.callApex. This creates a separate request for each remoting call, preventing the Apex CPU limit from being reached prematurely.
LCC.callApex("...RemotingMethod...", "...RemotingParam...", {
    buffer: false  // Create a new request for each call
})

By setting buffer: false, each remoting call is executed separately, creating a new request and avoiding the batching that can lead to quickly reaching the Apex CPU limit when making multiple concurrent calls.
This allowed me to make multiple concurrent remoting calls without them being batched into the same request and potentially reaching the Apex CPU limit too quickly.
I hope this helps anyone else who needs to make multiple concurrent remoting calls without hitting the Apex CPU limit too soon.
Ref link :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm?search_text=remoteaction

This is for visualforce remoting and has been around for a very long time. This buffering is also known as boxcarring. There are some old blogs about it, like this one, and there has been discussion of boxcarring in the context of LWCs as well.

You need to improve this answer to at least include an example call showing setting the buffer property. As it stands this is pretty much a link-only answer and those are prone to broken links over time, losing their value if the answer doesn't include some more detail directly.

@PhilW thank you for your feedback I have updated my answer

I'm rather surprised that setting buffer to true resolved the limit issue since it is by setting buffer to false that you turn off boxcarring. The documentation even says that true is the default.
